# Facebook API error 191- while using Facebook toolkit in salesforce

Tags: facebook

I am trying to integrate Facebook and Salesforce using Force.com Facebook Toolkit, but I am getting the following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 191
  }
}
```

Need Help.

Comment: Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691782/facebook-api-error-191 (but with no knowledge of the "Force.com Facebook ToolKit") I would guess that website URL you have registered in your Facebook app definition does not match the actual address of your salesforce org.

Answer (score 1):

Only two reasons:

1) You have assigned wrong redirect_uri in you facebook connected app so it doesn't match with the redirect_uri you have passed in parameter. Also take care of protocols like: https:// doesn't match with http://

2) Do not provide IP address or something which is different from standard domain name/address as redirect URI ex: 127.0.0.1 won't work.